# Trying to setup Qt: 'x64' conflicts with target machine type 'x86' while running nmake

Tags: c++, qt

I am trying to set up Qt4 on my 64bit Windows 10 environment. I have successfully ran the `configure` script, however when I try to run `nmake` I get the following error:

```
link /LIBPATH:"c:\Qt\4.8.5\src\tools\bootstrap\release" /NOLOGO /INCREMENTAL:NO /SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE /OUT:..\..\..\bin\moc.exe @C:\Users\Evan\AppData\Local\Temp\nm1BD8.tmp
release\main.obj : fatal error LNK1112: module machine type 'x64' conflicts with target machine type 'X86'
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: '"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\BIN\link.EXE"' : return code '0x458'
Stop.
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: '"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\BIN\nmake.exe"' : return code '0x2'
Stop.
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: 'cd' : return code '0x2'
Stop.
```

I know the problem is the conflict of the two system types (x64/x86) But I don't know how to get passed this problem.

All I'm trying to do is run `nmake` in a command line. I have ran `vcvarsall` before `nmake` as well in the Visual Studio 14 folder. Any ideas?

Comment: You probably configured with the wrong Visual Studio command prompt or ran the wrong vcvarsall.

Comment: Is there a x64 version of vccarsall/command prompt?

Comment: I can tell you that I have successfully buit Qt-4.8.5 in x64 mode on windows 10.

Comment: ***Is there a x64 version of vccarsall/command prompt?*** Yes.

Comment: @drescherjm any idea where I could find them and use them to build qt4?

Comment: The batch file you want isn't even called vcvarsall anymore, it's either vcvars32.bat or vcvars64.bat   Even my install of Visual Studio 9.0 has separate filenames.  Look in your Visual Studio install directory under VC\bin and VC\bin\amd64.